# Convert curl POST command to HttpClient code with VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, http-post, httprequest

I have this old code using curl:

```
writer.WriteLine("curl.exe -s -X POST --cookie-jar C:\curl.cookies -F ""username=user"" -F ""pwd=pass"" http://192.168.2.170/goform/UserLogin")

writer.WriteLine("curl.exe -s --cookie C:\curl.cookies --cookie-jar C:\curl.cookies -F 'secondi=1 -F 'decimi=0' -F 'outputNumber=1' http://192.168.2.170/goform/con_SetOutput")
```

I need to make the same call using an http client with POST, how can I do it?

I put togheter this sub that is running fine but isn't produce the expected result:

```
Public Sub FaiChiamataAPI()
        Dim url As String = "http://192.168.2.170/goform/UserLogin"
        Dim postData As String = "username=user&pwd=pass"

        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
        request.Method = "POST"
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        request.KeepAlive = False

        Using streamWriter As New StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())
            streamWriter.Write(postData)
        End Using

        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

        Using streamReader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
            Dim result As String = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
            ' Gestisci la risposta qui
        End Using

        ' Chiamata POST successiva
        Dim outputUrl As String = "http://192.168.2.170/goform/con_SetOutput"
        Dim outputData As String = "secondi=1&decimi=0&outputNumber=1"

        Dim outputRequest As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(outputUrl), HttpWebRequest)
        outputRequest.Method = "POST"
        outputRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

        Using outputStreamWriter As New StreamWriter(outputRequest.GetRequestStream())
            outputStreamWriter.Write(outputData)
        End Using

        Dim outputResponse As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(outputRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

        Using outputStreamReader As New StreamReader(outputResponse.GetResponseStream())
            Dim outputResult As String = outputStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
            ' Gestisci la risposta qui
        End Using

        Console.WriteLine("Chiamate POST completate.")
    End Sub
```

I have to add request.KeepAlive = False and system.net httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" in my web.config because otherwise it will give me a server error "System.Net.WebException: The server committed a protocol violation"

I did use curl on the target device to know what is expecting (curl -i -X "POST" -F "file=C:/file.xml" "http://192.168.2.170/goform/UserLogin?username=user&pwd=pass") and this is the answer:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: GoAhead-Webs
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Expires: 0
Content-Type: text/html
Set-Cookie:User=webterm~; path=/
Set-Cookie:SessionId=73865833933~; path=/
Set-Cookie:group=USERS; path=/

<HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV=refresh content=0;URL=../IT/></HEAD></html>
```

I don't need to read any answer from the called ip, it's a device that has to execute an internal function triggered by my http request.

Comment: If you're needing to do a POST request, wouldn't you be better using `Await client.PostAsync(URI)`?

Comment: @Hursey of course you're right, I pasted the wrong bit '-.- I just edited it. Please note that it's the first time I do a POST with vb.net and I'm using code I found

Answer (score 0):

I did it, this is my solution:

```
Public Sub httpPOST_CCN(ip As String, user As String, pwd As String, digout As Integer, sec As Integer, dec As Integer)
        Dim CookieJar As New CookieContainer
        Dim url As String = String.Format("http://{0}/goform/UserLogin", ip)
        Dim postData As String = String.Format("username={0}&pwd={1}", user, pwd)

        ' Effettua la prima chiamata POST per l'autenticazione
        Dim reader As StreamReader

        Dim Request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url)

        Request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.14) Gecko/20080404 Firefox/2.0.0.14"
        Request.CookieContainer = CookieJar
        Request.AllowAutoRedirect = False
        Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        Request.Method = "POST"
        Request.ContentLength = postData.Length

        Dim requestStream As Stream = Request.GetRequestStream()
        Dim postBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData)

        requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length)
        requestStream.Close()

        Dim Response As HttpWebResponse = Request.GetResponse()

        For Each tempCookie In Response.Cookies
            CookieJar.Add(tempCookie)
        Next

        reader = New StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream())
        Response.Close()

        ' Chiamata POST successiva
        Dim outputUrl As String = String.Format("http://{0}/goform/con_SetOutput?secondi={1}&decimi={2}&outputNumber={3}", ip, sec, dec, digout)

        Dim RequestOut As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(outputUrl)
        RequestOut.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.14) Gecko/20080404 Firefox/2.0.0.14"
        RequestOut.AllowAutoRedirect = False
        RequestOut.CookieContainer = CookieJar

        Dim ResponseOut As HttpWebResponse = RequestOut.GetResponse()

        reader = New StreamReader(ResponseOut.GetResponseStream())
        ResponseOut.Close()
    End Sub
```